# Handling a value that is not specified in a 'switch' statement

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, switch-statement

I have a "Security Panel" with numerical buttons that allow a user to enter a password (code) into a `TextBox` control. I am processing this password in a `switch` statement.

**Problem:** When the user enters a password incorrectly, I would like to display "Access Denied" with the date and time. How can I do this?

**Code:**

```
string password = inputtxt.Text;

switch (password)
{
    case "1432":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "INFO First Year Students"); 
        break;
    case "2543":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "INFO Second Year Students"); 
        break;
    case "3543":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "B.Tech Students"); 
        break;
    case "2645":
    case "2646":
    case "2647":
    case "2648":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "CSIT Faculty"); 
        break;
    case "8888":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "IET Staff"); 
        break;
    case "":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " + "Pl Enter a Valid Code"); 
        break;
    case "0":
        listBox.Items.Add(DateTime.Now + " " +
            "Received Request - Will be there   shortly"); 
        break;
}

inputtxt.Text = "";
```

Comment: You need a default case

Comment: You need to understand how [switch statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) works. This [tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/switch-statement/) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add a `default` case to your `switch`:

```
default:
     MessageBox.Show("Access denied");
     break;
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm. Could you explain how/why this worked?

Comment: @RyanMcCloy If none of the cases in a switch statement are valid then it will default to the aptly named `default` case if its present.